# How to do an if else in ajax passing data to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How do I do an if else in $.ajax for the following condition:  If the ID field is >0 then pass to json only the id field, else pass everything else.  Thanks for your help.  Grant

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'artist_update_event.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {
        artist_create_event_name: $('#artist_create_event_name').val(),
        artist_create_event_desc: $('#artist_create_event_desc').val(),
        name: $('#name').val(),
        city:  $('#city').val(),
        state:  $('#state').val(),
        location:  $('#location').val(),
        zipcode:  $('#zipcode').val(),
        event_address : $('#event_address').val(),
        event_address2 : $('#event_address2').val()
    },
    success : function(data){
        $('#art_event_message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' :     'success')
            .text(data.msg).show(500);
        if (data.error === true) {
            if (data.goto == 1)       {
                delete json;
            }
            else {
                $('#artist_create_event').show(500);
                delete json;
            }
        }
        if (data.error === false) {
            $('#artist_create_event').show(500);
            delete json;
        }
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#art_event_message').removeClass().addClass('error')
        alert('The error was: '+errorThrown);
        alert('The error was: '+XMLHttpRequest);
        alert('The error was: '+textStatus);
        //                  .text('response.Text').show(500);
        $('#artist_create_event').show(500);
    }
});

return false;
}

});
```

Comment: What ID field? There is no `id` or `ID` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Did you leave something out? There are extra close braces at the end that don't match anything.

Comment: if you need to make elements in the `data:` option conditional, you should create the object before calling `$.ajax`. Then you can use `if/else` to add different properties to the object.

Comment: Id is data field? means you are passing Id in data attribute such as city ,name etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the data in a variable before calling `$.ajax`, then pass the variable to it.

```
var dataObj;
if (id > 0} {
    dataObj = { id: id };
} else {
    dataObj = {        
        artist_create_event_name: $('#artist_create_event_name').val(),
        artist_create_event_desc: $('#artist_create_event_desc').val(),
        name: $('#name').val(),
        city:  $('#city').val(),
        state:  $('#state').val(),
        location:  $('#location').val(),
        zipcode:  $('#zipcode').val(),
        event_address : $('#event_address').val(),
        event_address2 : $('#event_address2').val()
    };
}
$.ajax({
    url : 'artist_update_event.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: dataObj,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Barmar, I tried what you coded and it works great except that the if statement doesn't execute.  Not quite sure if the id is being recognized or not.  Any suggestions?? Thanks

Comment: Got it.  In addition to the code from Barmar, I added id =   $('#id').val() and it works great.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Barmar How would you retrieve the parameter like `name` or `city`? You can't use `request.getparameter('name') ` anymore though.

Comment: @Daredevil When the `if` condition is true, those parameters aren't needed. I assume the server script will look up all the details in a database, keyed by the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `dataToPass` variable and set its value regarding your condition.

```
var dataToPass = (obj.id && obj.id > 0) ? 
                     { ID: obj.id } :
                     { /* everything else */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take id in php first after it you can pass the id in java script ajax code

```
var name_string='<?php echo $irfan;?>';
var nam=parseInt(name_string);
```

e.g

```
$user_id=get from db here and after it send in $ajax

$(document).ready(function(){         

        var name_string='<?php echo $irfan;?>';// here this line to get data in javascript 
        var nam=parseInt(name_string);// here this line to parse data string to int 
        $('#view_more').click(function(){
          $.ajax({                   
            url: '/15_augs/events/mytest/',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { no:x,myname:nam,},
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function (results) {
        }
}
```